# Onclick needs to be happening on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code with a little Javascript inside it, when I press the button it calculates a price and shows the result. But I want this price to be calculated at soon as the page loads. I figured this must be what the onload is for, but that didn't help?

```
<div>
    <p>200</p>
    <div id="label1"></div>
    <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate('calcObject1','label1',200)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just call the `calculate` function?

Comment: `$(window).on('load',function(){calculate('calcObject1','label1',200)});` or use document ready pseudo event instead

Comment: How did you use onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to raise the click event here, as you can just call the `calculate` event when the page has loaded:

```
$(function() {
    calculate('calcObject1', 'label1', 200);
});
```

Or using native JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    calculate('calcObject1', 'label1', 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the code in `onload` event of the `body` element: `<body onload="calculate(...)">`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged jQuery, you can use this to trigger a click event.

Give your button an id, such as `btn1`, then call:

```
$('#btn1').click();
```

or if you dont like id's, you can do this, but it will click all buttons on the page:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click();
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document ready`, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    calculate(..);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onload property of the body tag. Take a look in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kostisalex/wHLn3/20/

```
<body onload="calculate('fromBody1','fromBody2',200)">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate('calcObject1','label1',200)" />
    </div>
```